# Why is the Pharo definition of arithmetic + and - basically duplicated code?

Tags: math, smalltalk, pharo

I was looking through the internals of Pharo and noticed that the definition of arithmetic + and - look very much alike:

```
+ aNumber
"Refer to the comment in Number + "
aNumber isInteger ifTrue:
    [self negative == aNumber negative
        ifTrue: [^ (self digitAdd: aNumber) normalize]
        ifFalse: [^ self digitSubtract: aNumber]].
aNumber isFraction ifTrue:
    [^Fraction numerator: self * aNumber denominator + aNumber numerator denominator: aNumber denominator].
^ aNumber adaptToInteger: self andSend: #+
```

and

```
- aNumber
"Refer to the comment in Number - "
aNumber isInteger ifTrue:
    [self negative == aNumber negative
        ifTrue: [^ self digitSubtract: aNumber]
        ifFalse: [^ (self digitAdd: aNumber) normalize]].
aNumber isFraction ifTrue:
    [^Fraction numerator: self * aNumber denominator - aNumber numerator denominator: aNumber denominator].
^ aNumber adaptToInteger: self andSend: #-
```

As I see it, this is completely against the OO way of designing things and is generally bad. Why doesn't anybody find a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing I can think of is:

```
- aNumber
    ^self + aNumber negated
```

However, this will have a cost:

- creation of another intermediate LargeInteger, or Fraction
- two more message sends to perform the - operation

What we see here is a tribute to optimization. Not premature optimization, this is a low level operation used extensively.

There are other things in this code which are not perfect:

- usage of isInteger and isFraction might as well be replaced with some kind of double-dispatching
- the methods digitAdd: and digitSubtract: work for integers stored as sign - magnitude rather than 2-complement which is a not completely obvious implementation detail and would deserve a comment - or maybe should better be renamed digitAddMagnitude: digitSubtractMagnitude:

Answer (score 0):

It's not against OO - the behaviour is encapsulated, hiding the complicated behaviour behind a simple API.  (or message protocol, as we like to call it in Smalltalk).

There's a lot of code duplication.  It would be possible to put a layer of indirection in, and keep the code in one common place - but this is an example of sacrificing compactness for speed - trading off memory footprint for  speed.  It also trades speed at the expense of the [OnceAndOnlyOnce](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OnceAndOnlyOnce) that I believe is your principle concern.

In the first Smalltalk I used, [LearningWorks](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221555761_OU_LearningWorks_A_Customized_Programming_Environment_for_Smalltalk_Modules), (based on a ParcPlace implementation, iirc) the `-` function simply negated the argument and then called the `+` function.   This made the `-` operation slower than the `+` operation.

There are lots of potential trade-offs and optimisations in software development - the principal ones are speed for memory footprint (and vice versa), speed of execution for speed of development (and vice versa), and ease of getting something working right now versus ease of keeping it working and tweaked over the long haul.

OO development is generally optimised around optimising for speed of development at the expense of speed of execution, using high-level languages that are faster to develop in, but which run more slowly; optimising for long-term maintainability over immediacy; and using up a lot of memory to wring as much performance out of the naturally-slower code as is possible.

These are however, generalisations.  There are counter-examples to all of them, I'm pretty sure.